# How to show file upload status in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a controller that takes a lot of data by file and inserts it into the database. How can I show the user some status about how much code is run.

For example, I want to show statuses like, "file upload was done", "data is being validated", "data is inserted" etc. My initial approach was to use the session.

I inserted something like the following in appropriate places on controllers.

```
..
..code for file upload
..
session()->put('_order_upload_status','file upload done');

..
..code for validation
..
session()->put('_order_upload_status','data is being validated');
```

Then on the front end, I ran a bit of js code to get the status periodically.

```
function intervalAction()
  {
    var intervalID = window.setInterval(getStatus, 500);
  }
function getStatus()
  {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = '{{ route('order.upload.getStatus') }}';
    request.open('GET',url,true);

    request.onload = function(){
      document.getElementById('percentageModalTextBox').innerHTML = this.response
    };
    request.send();
  }
```

The url `{{ route('order.upload.getStatus') }}` does nothing more than to get the session data.

However, this approach is not working. I can get the correct session only after the file upload controller runs completely. So I am getting nothing for a long time and only the last status after everything is over.

How can I show the status update to the user?

Comment: for real time status i think you need to use web socket

Comment: I don't want anything super accurate. I want to update the user maybe each second that this part was completed. Can't it be done without a web socket?

Comment: without websocket you can use pulling like `ajax` setIntertval

Comment: How can it be done? I have already used JS setInterval. How is it different from the ajax one?

Comment: You better search about it yourself and let us know when you face issue implementing it.

Comment: @AhmadKarimi.. For which purpose I would use Ajax? I am already trying with JS to get the session data. How can I use Ajax to get the statuses from controller?

Comment: @NabilFarhan, I think using Ajax is on the only viable solution here and Using websocket facilitates the guidance or proper use of Ajax to send message back and forth within your Application. I suggest you study implementing websocket in your Laravel Application. You will find your way then.